# How to show point data as a colored map?

Tags: point, interpolation, visualisation, inverse-distance-weighted, spatial-analysis

Im doing one, I would say, simple analysis, but Im rookie when it comes to GIS, so I need help. So, I have data of CPT (cone penetration test) which our firm conducted over the years and within that data we have information about liquefaction potential of the location of the test. Liquefatction is in range from 1 (low probability) to 5 (high probability). Every location has one defined probability (for example 3-medium probability). I have put that liquefaction data like points in QGIS and they are georeferenced. Now I would like to create some kind of a map out of those points to show how liquefaction probability changes from location to location and what is the estimated probability of it at the locations I dont have data at. I have around 109 points. I think that the right way to do it is IDW interpolation, but I am not sure.

Can you give me advice about what to do and how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at the heatmap renderer: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#index-12 You could also create this as a permanant raster: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html#heatmap-kernel-density-estimation

Comment: @Babel has a good idea.  Also related is Graduated. 
 renderer. Just right-click your layer and select Properties. 
 
 The little paintbrush icon is 'Control Feature Properties" https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#graduated-renderer